# Javascript object props

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, properties, undefined

The [syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp) in JavaScript for accessing the property of an object is:

`object.property` or `object["property"]` or `object[property]`

I was trying out this [lesson](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/testing-objects-for-properties) on freeCodeCamp:

```
var myObj = { gift: "pony", pet: "kitten", bed: "sleigh" };

function checkObj(checkProp) {
  if( myObj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp) )
    return myObj[checkProp];

  return "Not Found";
}

checkObj("gift");
```

... the console displays the expected prop with `object[property]` syntax and `undefined` otherwise. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *property* is a variable, to access the object property dynamically you must have to use [Bracket (`[]`) notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation). Otherwise it will always give you `undefined`.

```js
var myObj = { gift: "pony", pet: "kitten", bed: "sleigh" };

function checkObj(checkProp) {
  if( myObj.hasOwnProperty(checkProp) )
    return myObj[checkProp];

  return "Not Found";
}

console.log(checkObj("gift"));
console.log(checkObj("g"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Because only `object[property]` lets you to use a dynamic property (kept in a variable, in your particular case - `checkProp`).

The others - `object.property` or `object["property"]` refer **directly** to a prop named `property`, and since **there isn't** such prop as `property`, you'll receive `undefined`.

Comment: Additional `object["proper ty"]` may contain spaces whereas `object.proper ty` may not